# Eigenvector matrix of a real positive matrix to be from $SO(n)$. How?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Suppose I have a positive real matrix of dimension $n$ and as such there exists a diagonalizing (rotation) matrix that belongs to $SO(n)$. How do I force `Eigensystem` to produce this matrix? Example:

```
eigsys = Eigensystem[{{Cosh[x], Sinh[x]},{Sinh[x], Cosh[x]}}]
```

where $\cosh{x}\geq\sinh{x}$ produces

```
{{Cosh[x] - Sinh[x], Cosh[x] + Sinh[x]}, {{-1, 1}, {1, 1}}}
```

Then

```
Det[eigsys[[2]]] (* is -2 *)
```

So after orthogonalization, the matrix is from $O(2)$ rather than from $SO(2)$. The rotation matrix is from $O(2)$ even if I set e.g. $x=2$.

Comment: My guess about this is that the transformation matrix can be *chosen* to be from SO(2). Try this: `Det@Transpose@Reverse@eigsys[[2]]`. Basically, if you switch the order of the eigenvectors, you get a matrix with determinant 2 rather than -2.

Comment: Are your matrices always symmetric?

Comment: For small matrices, switching eigenvectors or flipping one eigenvector to its opposite based on the sign of the determinant would work. For larger matrices, computing the determinant is quite expensive. So, this is actually a good question!